# Editing associated models data in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, model-associations, updatemodel

I'm using CakePHP 2.3.6. I have some Models in my project, which are associated and I defined the association explicitly. Now, I have an Edit form, where I retrieve all the models data, and trying to edit those data in the corresponding models. But, edition is not happening, instead, new rows are created in the associated tables.

Here is my associations among the models :

in the model `User.php` :

```
public $hasMany=array('Education'=>array(
                            'className'=>'Education
                            'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
                      ),
                      'Experience'=>array(
                            'className'=>'Experience',
                            'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
                      ),
                      'Employment'=>array(
                            'className'=>'Employment',
                            'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
                      ),
                      'ProfessionalQualification'=>array(
                            'className'=>'ProfessionalQualification',
                            'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
                      )
)
```

in the model `Education.php` :

```
public $belongsTo=array('User'=>array(
                            'className'=>'User',
                            'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
                        )
)
```

in the model `Experience.php`

```
public $belongsTo=array('User'=>array(
                            'className'=>'User',
                            'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
                        )
)
```

in the model `Employment.php` :

```
public $belongsTo=array('User'=>array(
                            'className'=>'User',
                            'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
                        )
)
```

in the model `ProfessionalQualification.php` :

```
public $belongsTo=array('User'=>array(
                            'className'=>'User',
                            'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
                        )
)
```

Now, in the Edit form (`View/Users/edit.ctp`) :

```
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('User.name');
echo $this->Form->input('User.username');
echo $this->Form->input('User.password');
echo $this->Form->input('User.address');
echo $this->Form->input('User.phone');
echo $this->Form->input('Education.0.degree');
echo $this->Form->input('Education.0.passing_year');
echo $this->Form->input('Experience.0.title');
echo $this->Form->input('Experience.0.description');
echo $this->Form->input('Employment.0.company');
echo $this->Form->input('Employment.0.description');
echo $this->Form->input('ProfessionalQualification.0.certificate');
echo $this->Form->input('ProfessionalQualification.0.description');
echo $this->Form->submit('Save');
echo $this->Form->end();
```

in the `UsersController.php` controller :

```
public function edit(){
  $this->set('title_for_layout','Edit CV');
  if(!AuthComponent::user('id'))
     throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid User'));
  $user=$this->User->findById(AuthComponent::user('id'));
  if(!$user)
     throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid User'));
  if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')){
     if(!$this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)){
        $this->Session->setFlash('Sorry, your info could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'edit'));
     }
  }
  if(!$this->request->data)
     $this->request->data=$user;
}
```

Here, I am trying `saveAll()` function on `User` model. I Also tried using `save()` & `saveAssociated()` functions, but same result. It doesn't change the corresponding rows in the tables, instead, it creates a new row in all tables, accept the `users` table, this table successfully gets the new values and updates the values.

What should I do ? Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `updateAll` instead of `saveAll` ?

Comment: How should I use it, like this : $this->User->updateAll($this->request->data) ? Its also not working, instead, it gives an error : Array to string conversion

Comment: Initialize `$this->User->id` with user id before calling `$this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)`

Comment: Yeah, I did, but same result. Thanks @Console

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to make it works (in theory) but I'm not sure it's the best and, it's not "secure": Adding the id for related field in your form, with hidden field, like so:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->hidden('User.id');
echo $this->Form->input('User.name');
/* ... */
echo $this->Form->hidden('Education.0.id');
echo $this->Form->input('Education.0.degree');
/* ... */
echo $this->Form->hidden('Employment.0.id');
echo $this->Form->input('Employment.0.company');
/* ... */
echo $this->Form->submit('Save');
echo $this->Form->end();
```

You should check in your controller that the `id` of your associated models match the `id` of your main model, if not people will be able to edit associated model not linked with their user model.

**Edit:** This is an edit for further explanation about the discussion in comment.

When you have `hasMany` relationship, like so:

```
public $hasMany = array('Experience') ; // In User class
```

You have to specify ID when saving the relation, if not the Cake engine cannot infer that you want to update a model instead of saving one.

```
$data = array(
    'User' => array(
        'id' => 33,
        'name' => 'Holt'
    ),
    'Experience' => array(
        array(
            /* 'id' => 45, */
            'name' => 'PHP'
        )
    )
) ;
$this->User->saveAssociated($data) ;
```

Here, you know that the `User` you're refering to is `Holt` with the id `33`, and so you know that the experiences in the following array refers to this user. But, if you don't specify the `id` field in the `Experience` array, **how the engine would know which experience you're refering to**?

If the relation was a `belongsTo`, it's easy to infer that's the `Experience` related to user `Holt` (there is only one `Experience` per user according to relation `belongsTo` or `hasOne`), and by the way you wouldn't have a nested array.

There are different ways to tell the engine you want to update a model, the 2 I use are:

- Setting the `id` value in the `data` array (like above)
- Setting the `$this->Model->id` value in your controller: This value is implicitely set when you do a `$this->Model->read` or a `$this->Model->find` (like you do)

What I'm sure, is that the first option works for associated model (like in the above `data` array if you uncomment the id), **I'm not sure** that the second works for associated model, like doing `$this->User->Experience->id = ...`, you can try it, I cannot check it right now.

Comment: Yeah, I know this trick, but I don't like it. If I have to update associated values like this, then why should I use association ? I could simply save(update) all tables individually. By the way, thanks for your help. @Holt

Comment: @SubhasishSaha Yes I know it's tricky. I don't see where you retrieve the post data in your code, could you check it?

Comment: @SubhasishSaha I was speaking about your post, you're saving the `$user` variable instead of `$this->data`.

Comment: ooops, mistake, I updated the question. Thanks :) @Holt

Comment: @SubhasishSaha In fact, I think you have to give the `id` of your associated fields because these are `hasMany` relations so Cake don't knwow if it's existing or new row. Not specifying the `id` works only with `belongsTo` relations.

Comment: Its working now ! Thanks a lot :) . So, I have to explicitly specify the IDs of the tables for hasMany association, right ? @Holt

Comment: @SubhasishSaha I'm not 100% sure and there I didn't really look into the doc to see if there is something about that but logicaly it's not possible for Cake to detect if you want to update an existing row or to add a new row when you save a `hasMany` association, except if you give the id.

Comment: Oh, I don't know/understand the logic. Can you please tell me about that logic in detail ? You can give me a link to look up, since explaining in this comment box is not that easy :) . By the way, thanks again :) @Holt

Comment: @SubhasishSaha I've updated my answer, hope you understand now!

Comment: hey @Holt I am having similar kind of problem but only difference is I am trying to insert/update data through main model.. Please tell me where I am making mistake -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187586/savemany-for-update-multiple-records-at-a-same-time-in-cakephp-not-working?noredirect=1#comment42866042_27187586

Comment: @Holt why is the version with the .id in the hidden field not secure? I got my edit with assosiations working with it. But now I am not sure if I should use it.

Comment: @Isengo Because it allows users to change that `id` value (even if the field is hidden, it is easy to do so), so they could update or steal entries that do not belong to them.

Comment: @Isengo In your controller,  you could check that the entries you are saving either do not exist yet (you are going to create them) or already belongs to the associated model. There may be simpler way that I am not aware of thought.

Comment: alright, thanks for the information. have a good start in the week!